# @XMLRootElement versus @XmlType

Tags: xml, jaxb, jax-ws

What's the difference between annotating a class with `@XMLRootElement` and `@XMLType`. I've been annotating classes with `@XMLType` when the structure will be used more than once within an XML schema and with `@XMLRootElement` when it will be used only once - is this the best approach?

A different but related question which I'll include here. The `@XMLType` annotation has an propOrder attribute to specify in which order its elements appear - is there an equivalent for `@XMLRootElement`?

I'm using these annotations in conjunction with JAX-WS annotations to create web services if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference between `XmlRootElement` and `XmlType` is a matter of scoping. Remember this annotation is merely dictating the creation of the schema used to generate your XML. The `XmlRootElement` denotes a global element (with an anonymous or schema type):

```
<xs:element name=foo type="bar"> </xs:element> <-- schema type
```

while the `XmlType` is used to denote a local element (with an anonymous or complex type):

```
<xs:complexType name=bar> </xs:complexType> <-- complex type
```

The main differences in local/global here are in the hierarchy of the schema your object will appear in and whether you are declaring a schema type or complex type. The documentation for both of these annotations is well written and includes examples:

[`XmlRootElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html)

[`XmlType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html)

EDIT: Addressing the `propOrder` question: you can use it on a global element if you are also declaring a local type:

```
@XmlRootElement (name="PersonElement")
@XmlType (propOrder={"firstname", "lastname"})
public class People{
    @XmlElement
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
}
```

This will yield something like:

```
<xs:element name="PersonElement" type="People"/>
<xs:complexType name="People">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 17):

> I've been annotating classes with @XMLType when the structure will be
>   used more than once within an XML schema and with @XMLRootElement when
>   it will be used only once - is this the best approach?

One thing to know is that neither the `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlType` annotation is required.  They aren't the equivalent of `@Entity` from JPA.  You can use a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation without any annotations what so ever:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Below I'll explain what `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlType` do.

---

**`@XmlRootElement`**

There are times when your JAXB implementation needs to instantiate an object based only on the XML element that is being processed.  The `@XmlRootElement` annotation is the primary means of specifying this association.  Note if a class corresponds to more than one XML element then the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation should be used insteat,

**ROLE #1 - Specifying the Root Object**

`@XmlRootElement` is primarily used to specify the root object.  This is so when your JAXB implementation begins unmarshalling an XML document it knows what object to instantiate.  Almost all subsequent annotations will be based on information gathered from the parent class.

***Foo***

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class Foo {

    private String name;

}
```

***Bar***

```
public class Bar {

    private String name;

}
```

***XML***

```
<root>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
</root>
```

***Demo***

```
Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
Bar bar = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Bar.class).getValue();
```

**ROLE #2 - Substitution Groups**

The `@XmlElementRef` annotation delegates the type of object instantiated to the name/uri of the element.  This enables the mapping to the concept of substitution groups for representing inheritance.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

**ROLE #3 - Any Content**

`@XmlAnyElement` allows you to map a wild card section of your XML document.  If you specify `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` then elements associated with domain objects will be converted to the corresponding domain object.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

---

**`@XmlType`**

**ROLE #1 - Schema Gen**

By default a named complex type is generated for each Java class known to the JAXB context.  You can control the name of this type using the `@XmlType` annotation, or specify that an anonymous complex type should be generated by specifying the name as `""`.

**ROLE #2 - Inheritance and xsi:type**

By default JAXB leverages the `xsi:type` attribute as the inheritance indicator.  The value on this attribute corresponds to the name and namespace you have specified on the `@XmlType` annotation, or is defaulted based on the class.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

**ROLE #3 - Prop Order**

As you mention you can use the `@XmlType` to specify the property order.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html

**ROLE #4 - Factory Methods**

`@XmlType` allows you to specify a factory class and/or method that can be used to instantiate the domain object instead of the default constructor.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-factory-methods.html

---

> A different but related question which I'll include here. The @XMLType
>   annotation has an propOrder attribute to specify in which order it's
>   elements appear - is there an equivalent for @XMLRootElement?

No, the `propOrder` aspect belongs to the `@XmlType` annotation.  This makes sense since complex types are responsible for specifying an (or lack of) order.  You can of course use these annotations at the same time.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"foo", "bar"}
public class Root {
    ...
}
```