# How to map java.util.Map with associations in hibernate xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have entity `Person` as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "personName", length = 16, nullable = false)
    private String name;
.....................
}
```

I have entity `Teacher` as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PersonId")
public class Teacher extends Person implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, Child> childByName = new HashMap<>();
        ......................................
}
```

I have entity `Child` as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PersonId")
public class Child extends Person implements Serializable {
        ..............................
}
```

Map `Teacher.childByName` should map `name` property of `Child` entity as a key and `Child` entity as a value. The relationship between `Teacher` and `Child` is one-to-many.

I need this mapping to be in xml format.
For now I did this in Person.hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Person"
        table="Person">
        <cache usage="read-write" />

        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="name">
            <column name="name" length="24" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="surname">
            <column name="surname" length="36"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="address">
            <column name="address" length="32"></column>
        </property>
        <joined-subclass name="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Parent"
            table="Parent">
            <key column="person_id" foreign-key="parent_person" />
            <property name="job" column="WorkPlace" length="22" type="string" />
            <set name="children" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" lazy="true">
                <cache usage="read-write" />
                <!-- specifies foreign key column of child table -->
                <key column="ParentPK" />
                <one-to-many class="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Child" />
            </set>
        </joined-subclass>
        <joined-subclass name="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Child"
            table="Child">
            <key column="person_id" foreign-key="child_person" />
            <property name="toy" column="toy" length="55" type="string" />
            <many-to-one name="parent"
                class="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Parent" column="ParentPK"
                lazy="false" fetch="join" foreign-key="child_parent" />
            <set name="teachers" table="TeacherPupil" inverse="true" lazy="true">
                <key column="child_id" foreign-key="teacherPupil_child" />
                <many-to-many class="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Teacher"
                    column="teacher_id" />
            </set>
        </joined-subclass>
        <joined-subclass name="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Teacher"
            table="Teacher">
            <key column="person_id" foreign-key="teacher_person" />
            <property name="subject" column="subject" length="25" type="string" />
            <set name="children" table="TeacherPupil" lazy="false" fetch="join">
                <cache usage="read-write" />
                <key column="teacher_id" foreign-key="teacherPupil_teacher" />
                <many-to-many class="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Child"
                    column="child_id" />
            </set>
            <map name="childByName" table="Child_By_Name" embed-xml="true">
                <key column="childByName_id" />
                <index column="childName" type="string" />
                <one-to-many class="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Child" />
            </map>
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Unfortunately `<map>` doesn't even create separate table called `Child_By_Name`. Instead it creates columns `childByName` and `childName` in table `Child`. This is very strange.

So, how to map my `childByName` Map to be in separate table to reference `Child` as its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a TeacherPupil table you should use it for your Map association too:

```
<map name="childByName" table="TeacherPupil" inverse="true">

<key column="teacher_id" not-null="true"/>

<map-key-many-to-many column="name" class="Child"/>

<many-to-many class="Child"/>

</map>
```

Comment: Pls, see my full `Person.hbm.xml`. It has mapping for Child as well

Comment: Both the set and the map are targeting the same association so maybe you should replace the set with the map and if the teacher handles the association then remove the inverse true attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate all answers, but one more thing u can do is,
make an entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "ChildName")
@Table(name="ChildName")
public class ChildName{
@Id
private Long  id;
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "childId")
private Child child;
```

}

and join your column as

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Teacher")
@Table(name="Teacher")
public class Teacher {

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "childNameId")
private ChildName childName;
```

}

your whole code will like

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Teacher")
@Table(name="Teacher")
public class Teacher {

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "childNameId")
private ChildName childName;
```

}

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "ChildName")
@Table(name="ChildName")
class ChildName{
@Id
private Long  id;
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "childId")
private Child child;
```

}

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Child")
@Table(name="Child")
public class Child extends Person implements Serializable {
```

}

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
@Id
private Long id;
private String name;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

It is not map association it will work like that

Comment: Why is there @XmlRootElement annotation?

Comment: Maps a class or an enum type to an XML element.

Usage

The @XmlRootElement annotation can be used with the following program elements:
a top level class , 
an enum type
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520724/xmlrootelement-versus-xmltype