# JAXB parse xml document

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="2" yahoo:created="2016-02-17T21:25:49Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
   <results>
      <rate id="USDEUR">
         <Name>USD/EUR</Name>
         <Rate>0.8990</Rate>
         <Date>2/17/2016</Date>
         <Time>9:26pm</Time>
         <Ask>0.8991</Ask>
         <Bid>0.8990</Bid>
      </rate>
      <rate id="USDUAH">
         <Name>USD/UAH</Name>
         <Rate>26.9000</Rate>
         <Date>2/17/2016</Date>
         <Time>9:25pm</Time>
         <Ask>27.0000</Ask>
         <Bid>26.9000</Bid>
      </rate>
   </results>
</query>
```

I trying to parse this document by this code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="query")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Query {

   public List<Rate> rate = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlElement( name = "rate" )
    public void setQuery( List rate )
    {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
       @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Query{" +
            "rate=" + rate +
            '}';
}
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




 @XmlRootElement( name = "rate" )
    public class Rate {
        String id;

        @XmlElement( name = "id" )
        public void setId(String id){
            this.id = id;
        }

        String rate;

        @XmlElement( name = "rate" )
        public void setRate(String rate){
            this.rate = rate;
        }
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////

File file = new File("E://xml//2.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Query.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Query mu = (Query) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(mu);
```

What's wrong with it? 
thrice rewriting classes , stopped on this variant

In console : `Query{rate=[]}`

`ArrayList`  Rate isn't associated with nodes from the document
//dummy text

Comment: Are you getting any error? What's happening with the code provided?

Comment: Plase, update your question with the error you're getting so we can assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes were wrong.

**Query.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="query")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Query {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="rate")
    private List<Rate> results;

    public List<Rate> getRate() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setRate(List<Rate> rate) {
        this.results = rate;
    }
}
```

**Rate.java**

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "rate" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "rate", propOrder = {
        "rate"
    })
public class Rate {

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name="Rate")
    private String rate;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you.   What does that annotation mean? Programm works without it.         @XmlType(name = "rate", propOrder = {
                      "rate"
               }

Comment: [See here another stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520724/xmlrootelement-versus-xmltype) Anyway feel free to up to vote.