# Apache CXF : Is XmlRootElement optional?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I'm putting in place a webservice in a "bottom-to-top" (contract-last) style.

I have the following web method:

```
@WebMethod
void addPerson(Person person);
```

Where Person is a simple POJO :

```
class Person {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   // Getters and setters
}
```

Everything works fine.
Question : why in many tutorials many people add the `XmlRootElement` annotation and implements the `Serializable` interface ? Why my model works out of the box without having to write it like this ?

```
@XmlRootElement
class Person implements Serializable {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   // Getters and setters
}
```

Regards

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520724/xmlrootelement-versus-xmltype) should answer your question.